# How to use Concat() & Substring in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

For question purposes I will use minimal data for my examples.

I have a table called `table1` and a column named `test` that looks like this:

```
test
5012
```

I am able to add an extra zero <s>behind</s> before the result of column `test` using this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('0',test) as x from table1
```

this is the result of the query:

results table: table1

```
  x
05012
```

Now I have another table called `table2` looking like this:

```
test    test2
05012     1
```

My question is, how do I join the two tables together based on that query above and concat the `table1` with column `test2` from `table2`? Making sure the first 4 characters of both columns `test` from both tables match together?

This is how table 1 should look like:

```
 Afterquery
  050121
```

Comment: Added answer with the substring requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am curious why you wouldn't simply use `table2`?

```
select concat(t2.test, t2.test2) as afterquery
from table2 t2;
```

`table1` doesn't seem to play a role.

If you want values in `table2` filtered by `table1`, you can use `exists`:

```
select concat(t2.test, t2.test2) as afterquery
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t2.test = concat('0', t1.test)
            );
```

You *can* express this as a `join`:

```
select concat(t2.test, t2.test2) as afterquery
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.test = concat('0', t1.test);
```

This is useful if you want columns from both tables -- but that is not necessary to answer the question.  On the other hand, this runs the risk of duplication if there are multiple matches.

Comment: "Making sure the first 4 characters of both columns test from both tables match together"? There should be a where some..where

Comment: @Kaddath . . . I see that the question asks that.  In the example and explanation given, I don't see that as necessarily a real requirement.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I need to match the table1 first 4 characters with the table2, this is because they are unique numbers. Basically acted as an id. And need to find the missing value from test1 that is shown inside table2 column test2

Answer (score 1):

I think that this should be the solution. You need to use `concat` in the join between `table1` and `table2`

```
SELECT CONCAT('0', table1.test, table2.test2) AS Afterquery
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON CONCAT('0',table1.test) = table2.test
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach with a sub-query:

```
select concat(concat_test, test2) test_results 
  from 
    (select concat('0', test) concat_test from table1) table_alias 
  join 
    table2 on substring(concat_test,1,4) = substring(test,1,4);
```